# I want user to select only one checkbox instead of multiple? How can I approach in angular?

Tags: angular, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes but I want user to select one checkbox but not multiple, if he check one checkbox and it returns checked value, else nothing should show up.can anyone help?

```html
<div class="form-check" *ngFor="let product of DisplayProductList">
    <label class="form-check-label text-break">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [value]="true" [(ngModel)]="product.isChecked"
            (change)="changeSelection($event)" />
        {{ product.template_name }}
        <span class="form-check-sign">
            <span class="check"></span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

```js
changeSelection(event: any) {
  this.checkedIDs = [];
  if (event.target.checked) {
    this.selectedItemsList = this.DisplayProductList.filter(
      (product, index) => {
        if (product.isChecked == true) {
          let splitstring = product.template_parameter;
          let sepratedArray = splitstring.split(',');
          this.variable1 = sepratedArray[0];
          this.variable2 = sepratedArray[1];
          this.checkedIDs.push(product.id);

          this.sendclusteridApi(this.productid);
          return product.isChecked;
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Normally, that's what radio buttons are there for.

Comment: Yeah, can we do it for checkboxes.

Comment: Why don't you use radiobuttons? Any particular reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is what radio buttons do, but if you need to implement the same functionality using checkboxes, you can achieve that like the following:

- Define a `selectedIndex` variable, and assign to it the index of the last checked checkbox.
- Bind the `ngModel` of the checkboxes to `[ngModel]="selectedIndex === index"` where the `index` is the index of the checkbox within the *ngFor loop.

```html
<div class="form-check" *ngFor="let product of DisplayProductList; let index = index">
  <label class="form-check-label text-break">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [ngModel]="selectedIndex === index"
        (change)="changeSelection($event, index)" />
    {{ product.template_name }}
    <span class="form-check-sign">
        <span class="check"></span>
    </span>
</label>
</div>
```

```js
selectedIndex: number;

changeSelection(event, index) {
  this.selectedIndex = event.target.checked ? index : undefined;

  // do your logic here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Amer. I have added your code, its working as expected but not returning my checked value, added code below,is there any wrong with my logic.?

Comment: changeSelection(event,index) {
    this.selectedIndex = event.target.checked ? index : undefined;
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.selectedItemsList = this.DisplayProductList.filter((product, index) => {
       
        if (product.isChecked == true) {
          let splitstring = product.template_parameter
          let sepratedArray = splitstring.split(',');
          this.variable1 = sepratedArray[0];
          this.variable2 = sepratedArray[1];
   
     return product.isChecked

        }
       
      }
      );
    } 
else {
 
    }

Comment: Where do you need to return/store the checked value exactly, please?

Comment: When checkbox is selected.I wanted to return,

Comment: I know, but what is the variable you want to assign the checked value to it?

Comment: Oh okay,in the this.selectedItemsList.

 <div class="pb-3 pl-3" *ngFor="let product of selectedItemsList">
  <a (click)="openCaseDetails(product.id)">{{ product.template_name}}</a>
in this i am displaying

Comment: Do you need to push the checked item to the `this.selectedItemList` array?

Comment: Yes Amar,thats how i am displaying checked value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237045/discussion-between-amer-yousuf-and-mercy).